# O pretérito imperfeito do indicativo: um tempo verbal versátil, ou usado incorretamente?

Tags: tempo-verbal

Noto que, em pt-BR, o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo é usado para indicar passado, presente, e até mesmo o futuro.  Como explicar esses usos?   Estão corretos quando usados na norma culta?  Vejamos os exemplos:

- Eu gostava muito de nadar quando eu era jovem. (passado)
- Eu tinha vontade de tomar um café agora. (presente)
- Se ela me convidasse, eu ia. (futuro)

Comment: É o mesmo no português de Portugal entre outras línguas ibéricas (usá-lo como se fosse condicional). Em castelhano ainda não forma parte do registro culto, mas em Portugal sim, já vi muitos cartazes no campus da universidade de Coimbra que o empregava assim. O uso não é nada novo, com séculos de uso.

Comment: Na terceira frase não se trata de futuro mas sim condicional. 
A segunda parece-me agramatical, eu interpretaria como imperfeito: tinha vontade mas já não tenho.
Já agora, a primeira é pretérito imperfeito (diferente de pretérito perfeito).

Comment: @RuiFonseca   Trata-se do futuro do pretérito, ou condicional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo frases completamente legítimas. Embora o Pretérito Imperfeito seja um tempo gramatical do passado, nem sempre apresenta características temporais.

Esta primeira frase

> (1) Eu gostava muito de nadar quando era jovem.

é de facto um exemplo do uso do Imperfeito com valor de passado. Mas o Pretérito Imperfeito tem muitas vezes uma forte dimensão aspetual e modal, e pode haver uma projeção para o futuro.

O teu exemplo denota um estado (*gostar de nadar*), pelo que a componente aspetual do Imperfeito não é muito saliente (o efeito é precisamente o de dar duração e remover o carácter télico (tender para um fim) do predicado, resultando  em processos atélicos ou mesmo em estados, possivelmente habituais).

Em todo o caso, suponho que a tua dúvida seja mais sobre as duas frases seguintes.

> (2) Tinha vontade de tomar um café (agora).

Neste caso, o Imperfeito refere-se a um futuro imimente, ideia que pode ser reforçada com *agora*. Este é um exemplo do valor modal do Imperfeito, que pode transmitir desejo, sugestão, ou pedido. Repara que *vontade* pode ser eliminado, e ficamos com uma frase semelhante, na qual se exprime um desejo ou uma sugestão:

> (3) Agora tomava um cafezinho.

Esta frase também pode ser articulada com um oração condicional, mantendo-se o valor modal do Imperfeito:

> (4) Se não tivesse de trabalhar, até ia beber um cafezinho.

Na tua última frase,

> (5) Se ela me convidasse, eu ia.

o valor modal desirativo não é muito óbvio (embora possamos ainda ler na frase um desejo). Mas o Imperfeito pode ser (pelo menos no português europeu) usado em lugar do Condicional na oração consequente de uma construção condicional, com valor simplesmente epistémico. Na *Gramática do Português* (cap. 15, pág. 520), temos os exemplos:

> - Se a Maria tivesse lido o jornal já **sabia** / *saberia* as notícias.
> - A Maria **tomava** / *tomaria* esse remédio se o médico lho recomendasse.

Na *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* (Maria Mateus e outras, 6.a ed. pág. 174), temos até a seguinte nota de rodapé:

> A substituição do Condicional pelo Imperfeito não é recente na língua portuguesa, pois Barbosa (1822/71) já o atesta. Tal acontece também em outras línguas românicas, como é o caso do italiano.

Como a mesma Gramática diz, o Imperfeito nem sempre é substituível pelo Condicional em casos em que está articulado com uma condição:

> - Se tiver tempo, amanhã **ia** à biblioteca. (leitura volitiva)
> - Se tivesse tempo, amanhã **ia/iria** à biblioteca. (condicional contrafactual)
> - *Se tiver tempo, amanhã **iria** à biblioteca.

Comment: Muito explicativa a resposta.

Comment: 3, 4 e 5 são usos do imperfeito com valor de condicional.

Answer (score -1):

"Eu gostava muito de nadar quando eu era jovem" está correto. Pretério imperfeito pode ser usado para expressar um hábito comum no passado, mas que não é mais no presente.

"Eu tinha vontade de tomar um café agora." está errado, deveria ser conjugado no presente. Mas posso falar "Eu tinha vontade de tomar um café até agora", que significa que você teve a vontade de tomar café, mas agora acabou, neste caso, o Pretérito Imperfeito indica a interrupção de uma ação.

Na frase "Se ela me convidasse, eu ia." está errado. A primeira parte "Se ela me convidasse" é o que chamamos de pretérito imperfeito do modo Subjuntivo, indicando uma condição no passado, mas que não foi realizado, e é seguido geralmente por um verbo no futuro do pretérito, que demonstra o "futuro alternativo" caso a condicional se tornasse realidade. Neste caso, "Se ela me convidasse, eu iria". Entretanto, é muito comum as pessoas contrair o "iria" como "ia", assim como contrair o "está" como "tá". Então, digamos que de forma informal, ainda é possível dar um ok nesta frase.

Comment: E muito comum ouvir-se "ah, eu tinha muita vontade de saber o que eles estão cochichando", com o significado de tenho vontade mas acho que não é possível.

Comment: -1. As frases declaradas "erradas" estão descritas em gramáticas e abundam na literatura.